# Can I nest AND and OR statements as part of a condition for allowing a Flow?

Tags: trigger, visual-workflow, conditional

I am fairly new to Flows, and I've never had to setup a complex condition. I can't figure out how to set up what I need. This is what I'm trying to get:

1. We have a Flow that is triggered if an Opportunity is created or updated.
2. The complexity is with the update.
3. We have a button for Mandatory Activate. This is a checkbox. The Flow should always continue if Mandatory Activate is checked.
4. We have a button for Mandatory Stop. The Flow should always stop if this checkbox is checked. (Unless Mandatory Activate is checked.)
5. If neither checkbox is checked, the Flow should still run if any of 3 things happen (here I need an OR block): is IsChanged true for the total_revenue_forecast OR total_arr_forecast OR StageName.

So there are two conditions that are absolute, and then 3 conditions that can be OR true.

I know how to put 3 conditions and have them set up as an OR , but I don't know how to combine that with the two checkboxes that each can operate on their own.

Should I write a custom formula? Some Apex code? Or should have multiple Decision boxes in the Flow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need one Decision branch, as you can create multiple outcomes. The first outcome is Mandatory Activate, which simply checks if Mandatory Activate is checked. The second outcome checks if Manidatory Activate is not checked and Manidatory Stop is checked. The third outcome is if both Manditory fields are unchecked and one of the three other conditions are true. You will need to customize the filter, but you should be able to just specify the conditions with the custom filter of `1 AND 2 AND (3 OR 4 OR 5)`; choose `Custom Condition Logic Is Met` for the Condition Requirements to Execute Outcome to enable the custom logic box.